# How can I get 3 columns on the same line?

Tags: html, css, percentage, multiple-columns

I am trying to get three columns on one line. It worked until I added some padding to the divs. I am using percentages for making it kinda responsive. The below is the CSS:

```
.contentLine .column {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 31%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: inherit;
}

.contentLine .last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

[**Here is my fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ednam/)

Did I make a mistake with the percentages?

Comment: The padding is added to the width of your elements. Check: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ Or you can just decrease the width by 2%

Comment: 1. Look at box sizing. 2. Change `.column` width to 30% because you have a right margin of 1% and padding 1%

Comment: Thanks for the link and the tips… So many answers in such a short time – I'm really impressed! :) But the `margin-right: 0;` on the last column isn't working…

Comment: @Retador: for that I think you have to look at the point mentioned in Love Trivedi's answer (about class attribute)

Comment: Ok… Now I also solved the problem with the last column thanks to @LoveTrivedi

Comment: @Harry You all are answering so super-fast that I didn't read that answer! :) Thanks!

Comment: @Retador: I have added the problematic piece of code from the fiddle into the question. Feel free to roll it back in-case there are any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/ggGNv/1/)**
Use margin-right:.5%;

```
.contentLine .column {
float: left;
margin: 0;
width: 31%;
margin-right: .5%;
padding: 1%;
position: inherit;
}
```

and change last column div like this. because you are using class attribute two times and you can use class attribute only one time in a single tag.

Use

```
<div class="column last">
```

not`<div class="column" class="last">` it is worng.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now the last column is also working properly…

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the width of your columns. With all the percentages and extra space added in, it all adds to over 100% which is why the third column will always be on the next line. Instead of 31%, try 30%.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the `width` of `.column` to 30%.

It currently goes to next line because, there are 3 boxes with `width` 31% (total 93%). They have `padding` (right and left) of 1% (so that totals upto 6%) and you have `margin-right` of 1% (which totals to 3%) and all together exceeds 100%.

```
.contentLine .column {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You explained it very well! :)